# Trying to use Bootstrap Nav Pills in React Router's NavLink

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router

I am having trouble using the default Bootstrap Nav pills as the links on the Navbar for my page, where they show if the pill is active or not. As I have the code, the NavLink is just in plain text and I can't seem to use any of the active styling from Bootstrap.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and React with React Router.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light">
        <ul className="nav nav-pills">{this.renderNavLinks()}</ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }

  renderNavLinks() {
    const navButton = {
      padding: "10px"
    };
    return this.props.navLinks.map(l => (
      <li className="nav-item" style={navButton}>
        <NavLink className="active" to={"/" + l.id}>{l.text}</NavLink>
      </li>
    ));
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

I want my NavBar to actively show what page is currently being displayed using Bootstrap's default pill style buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `nav-link` css class on the `NavLink` component.

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/" + l.id}>{l.text}</NavLink>
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#pills)